# Is redirecting to localhost:3001 a bad practice?

Tags: reactjs, redirect

I'm building a React application and I want to have some components open on localhost:3001. Is this a common practice? I attempted to use `window.location.href` and the navigation worked, but I'm unsure how to provide the component's path in the Routes.
Also, is it good practice to host different components individually in production?

Answer (score 0):

As your question first line states that you want to host your component somewhere and want to use them. You just need import somehow and than you can use them any no of time. there are plenty way of sharing components. Common practice depends upon what project you are working on, like small project can have all component in one app but large project which is handled by multiple people than they host there component and give access to use their component. You can to navigate to your component or pages basically we make small small component and combine them which makes a complete webpage. If you want navigate to different pages then you can use **React-router** and **React-router-dom** to navigate into the pages.

there you give path(basically **BASE_URL/**) to your Home Page. You can use as many as path as you want.
eg.

```
import Home from "./Home"
import Contact from "./Contact"
import About from "./About"

const router = createBrowserRouter([
{
    path: "/",
    element: <Home/>
  },{
    path: "/contacts/",
    element: <Contact />,
},
{
    path: "/about/".
    element: <About />
]);
```

Comment: I understood that. The problem is to navigate from one domain to the other and share the data across both the domains.